# How can I save components of an image into 3 different files in one take?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below code saves all RGB components as one file named as shown in picture. Is it possible that I can save each one of them to different files in one take? Also I dont understand why blue component has axes numbered and others not.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

#Image into RGB Components
img1 = np.array(Image.open('1.jpeg'))
figure, plots = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=1,figsize=(12, 4))
for i, subplot in zip(range(3), plots):
    temp = np.zeros(img1.shape, dtype='uint8')
    temp[:,:,i] = img1[:,:,i]   
    subplot.imshow(temp)
    plt.savefig("RedComponent.png", bbox_inches='tight')
    subplot.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last savefig call is happening before the axis is removed, that's why it's there on the final axes object.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

#Image into RGB Components
img1 = np.array(Image.open('1.jpeg'))
rgb = ("Red", "Green", "Blue")  # this gives you the basis for different filenames
figure, plots = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=1,figsize=(12, 4))

for i, subplot, channel in zip(range(3), plots, rgb):
    # create an additional figure within the loop for the single colour
    fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
    temp = np.zeros(img1.shape, dtype='uint8')
    temp[:,:,i] = img1[:,:,i]   
    subplot.imshow(temp)
    ax2.imshow(temp)
    # removing the axis before saving
    ax2.set_axis_off()
    subplot.set_axis_off()
    # Save single colour panel as its own file
    fig2.savefig("{}Component.png".format(channel), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close(fig2)  # remove the single-colour plot
# save the three-Axes figure separately once outside the loop
figure.savefig("AllComponents.png", bbox_inches='tight')


plt.show()
```